# Prime Vue Slider Component not functional

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, primevue

Added the Prime Vue Slider Component into my code following the documentation code (https://primefaces.org/primevue/slider) and this is what happens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXIX3.png)

If someone has the same issue help would be appreciated.

I only copied the plain documentation code example from Prime Vue and the slider appears as in the image, and has no functionalities.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No errors, console is clean

Comment: Are there any non-trivial differences between the rendered HTML in the official example and your rendered HTML? From the image, it seems that HTML (and maybe CSS) is broken. Can you check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools, and see if all the files (JS, CSS) have been loaded (no 404)?

Comment: You were right the css was a bit different then in the documentation, after copying it from the docs console the slider looks all right but still is not functional, after checking my network tab there is no 404, everything is loaded well (200 and 304). I assume i need to make a function with a event to solve the handle movement but shouldn't Prime Vue do the the job for me.. Nevertheless thank you for you help.